# Workaround for secondary workflow on tasks list

Tags: 2013, workflow, tasks, task-list

I need to overcome the limitation when one VS workflow creates tasks on task list, which also has another workflow attached to ItemCreated, and the secondary workflow is not triggered. Any ideas?

(I know the question has been asked before but I haven't found any workaround for this problem available)

EDIT:
I am sending mail notifications to users for whom approval tasks are created, it seems easier to implement it independently to run on creating task item, I have a pretty complex logic inside multi-level sequence and parallel approval actions. So the WF1 creates tasks, and WF2 runs on WF1's task list to implement mailing functionality.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are doing and what the issue is? The first WF is creating a task and you want the list that task is created on to also have a workflow? What is the purpose of that workflow? Just need more information.

Comment: @spevilgenius updated

Comment: When the first workflow creates items in the other list, is it doing this with a system update or are you disabling event firing? I believe that this is what may be happening as I have seen this before. I have written workflows that do that so it would NOT fire other workflows.

Comment: @spevilgenius basically WF1 is creating tasks using either SingleTask or CompositeTask activities (Visual Studio, SP2013), no custom code is used (and cannot be, since there are no code activities in 2013).

Comment: Yes, that is true. But your issue still points to those activities turning off event firing when they update another list. A simple check would be to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer that does a similar function and see if that starts the other workflow.

Comment: after checking it looks like basic workflow in SPD which creates a task does not trigger another WF attached to the task list.

Comment: That does seem to be a problem as I have not seen that before. Is the other workflow a VS workflow as well? I know it is a complex task, but it may be that you have to combine the workflows. Or, another test is to try the same thing on a different task list and see if it will fire a workflow.